# Vector Subscript Out Of Range opencv c++

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix, vector, graphics

I'm trying to write some code that uses OpenCV to first convert a video, frame by frame to its r,g chromaticity, then make that into a histogram for comparison.  However, I'm having some troubles with some operations not being allowed on vectors or matrices (and vice versa).

```
Mat src, res, out, hsv_vid;
vector<Mat> spl;
Mat spl_r, spl_g, spl_b;
Mat r_chroma, g_chroma, frame_chroma;

for(;;){
    cap1 >> src; //read video frame into src matrix
    if (src.empty()) break;

    //extract channels
    split(src, spl);
    spl_r = spl[2];
    spl_g = spl[1];
    spl_b = spl[0];

    //convert whole frame to chromaticity
    r_chroma = spl_r / (spl_r + spl_g + spl_b);
    g_chroma = spl_g / (spl_r + spl_g + spl_b);

    //convert matrix to vector
    vector<vector<Mat>> r_chroma_vec;
    for (int i = 0; i < r_chroma.rows; i++) {
        vector<Mat> row;    
        r_chroma.row(i).copyTo(row);
        r_chroma_vec.push_back(row);
    }
    vector<vector<Mat>> g_chroma_vec;
    for (int i = 0; i < g_chroma.rows; i++) {
        vector<Mat> row;    
        g_chroma.row(i).copyTo(row);
        g_chroma_vec.push_back(row);
    }

    merge(r_chroma_vec, frame_chroma);
    merge(g_chroma_vec, frame_chroma);

} //end for(;;)

//disp chromaticity test img
vector<int> compression_params;
compression_params.push_back(CV_IMWRITE_PNG_COMPRESSION); //use .PNG compression
compression_params.push_back(9);
try { imwrite("ChromaTest.png", frame_chroma, compression_params); } //write output matrix to file
catch (runtime_error& ex) { return -2; }
```

If I want to be able to do the division & addition to get my chromaticity then r_chroma & g_chroma must be matrices, then I cannot merge them.  If I have r_chroma & g_chroma as vectors, then I can merge them, but I cannot do the math operations on them.

Is there any way to merge() 2 matrices, or am I going about this the wrong way?  I'd appreciate it if someone could point me in the right direction.

Thanks for reading!

[edit]: Added matrix -> vector conversion to make merging to output Matrix possible.

Comment: `Vector Subscript Out Of Range`  This means you are accessing an out-of-bounds entry in the vector.  If you used arrays, the same error (but either a crash or silence from the runtime) would have occurred.  So it really isn't a `std::vector` issue.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I haven't run it yet.  VS2012 is just giving me red underlines because some operations are not allowed with matrices/vectors (ie. merge).  But you're saying there is a bounds error with spl[ ]?

Comment: Maybe its just me, but does this for loop have a closing bracket?  Perhaps you should show all of the code instead of just a snippet.

Comment: @Owl_Prophet Yes it does.  I've made some edits to reflect that.

Comment: dear, there's more wrong than right in your code in general. `       vector<int> row;    
        r_chroma.row(i).copyTo(row);` // nope, won't lead to desired result. `vector<uchar>`, maybe.

Comment: @berak yeah I noticed right after I posted.  Thanks for the help though.

Comment: it's all broken. please start from scratch. discard all those stupid loops

Comment: @berak Not a bad idea at this point haha.

Comment: @user1846359 I can't understand what is meant to be happening here. Either rephrase a lot of your question, or take berak's advice.

Answer (score 1):

[cv::merge](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#merge) is the counterpart of cv::split, 1st arg is a `vector<Mat>` or Mat[], 2nd arg is the result Mat.

so , you simply got the args wrong.

another  problem in your approach is this part:

```
r_chroma = spl_r / (spl_r + spl_g + spl_b);
```

yes, you can use the maths operators, but `(spl_r + spl_g + spl_b)` will saturate, the result Mat is still a uchar one.

[edit]: 1st try at fixing the vector problem:

```
vector<Mat> spl_new;
spl_new.push_back( spl_b ); // <-- ???
spl_new.push_back( g_chroma );
spl_new.push_back( r_chroma );

Mat result;
merge( spl_new, result );
```

Comment: Hmmm.  You're saying that my r_chroma & g_chroma should be a vector<Mat>?  But if that's the case, then I can't do the adding and dividing.  Also, if I can't use r,g = R,G / (R+G+B) then how should I go about getting chromaticity?  Thanks for the help so far :)

Comment: no, you've got to pack them into a vector before. what would be the 3rd (b) channel in the result picture ? the original one ?

Comment: I've made edits to the post.  I used for loops to simply put the Matrix (resulting from the math operations) into a vector to make merging to an output array possible.  But I'm getting a out of bounds error.  I've still got to work on that.  But what do you think so far?

Comment: let's say - i give up on you.

Comment: I thought chromaticity meant that each pixel only had r,g values as computed by r,g = R,G / (R+G+B).  So wouldn't the result only be 2 channels/pixel so there would be no (B)?  Or am I mistaken?  Should I set b to be a zero matrix?